# Time and date function in CLIPS

Tags: time, clips

is there a way to get current date or time (better if timestamp)  from
CPU in CLIPS?

Thank you,
Nicola

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the time function to retrieve the number of seconds that have passed since a prior date (defined by the particular implementation used by the platform specific library function called by CLIPS).

```
CLIPS> (time)
900973.658508
CLIPS> (time)
900977.658599
CLIPS>
```

You can also download and compile code for the 63x branch of CLIPS (https://sourceforge.net/p/clipsrules/code/HEAD/tree/branches/63x/core/) and use the gm-time and local-time functions provided.

```
CLIPS> (gm-time)
(2016 6 10 20 12 52 Friday 161 FALSE)
CLIPS> (local-time)
(2016 6 10 15 12 55 Friday 161 TRUE)
CLIPS>
```

The gm-time function returns Greenwich Mean Time and the local-time function returns local time. The values returned in the multifield are year, month, day, hour, minutes, day of week, days since beginning of year, and daylight savings time.